# Замена бесконечного цикла

Tags: c++, циклы

Можно ли заменить следующий бесконечный цикл на обычный цикл? Слышал, что всегда можно, но не понимаю как.

```
while (true) {
    if (c1(a)) {
        a = f1(a);
    }

    if (c2(a)) {
        break;
    }

    a = f2(a);
}
```

Здесь `f1, f2` - функции, возвращающие какое-то значение, зависящее от `a`, `c1, c2` - условия (функции, возвращающие `bool`), зависящие от `a`.

upd:

под обычным я понимаю без `break, continue, goto` и прочих хаков, а чтобы условие было не постоянным/пустым

Comment: Можно, но смысла никакого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заменить можно так

```
do {
  if (c1(a)) {
    a = f1(a);
  }

  cond = !c2(a);

  if (cond)
    a = f2(a);
} while (cond);
```

но в данном случае бесконечный цикл нагляднее

Comment: Для заметки, если кому интересно, сильно ли повляет на производительность: сделал бенчмарк кода из вопроса и этого: на маленьком колве итераций код из вопроса чуть быстрее, на большом -- одинаково

Comment: @леха: Проверять подобные минимальные изменения "на производительность", да еще и без информации о содержимом вызываемых функций - совершенно бессмысленное занятие, результаты которого абсолютно ничего не значат.

Answer (score 3):

Например можно так. Но я бы не сказал что это улучшит читабельность.

```
for (;!c2(a=!c1(a)?:f1(a));a=f2(a));
```

Внезапный код-гольф?

Comment: Работает, но не уверен, что пройдёт ревью)

Comment: @леха, `do-while` прям пройдет? Я бы лучше делал через `for`.

Comment: @леха ну попробовать можно) мне интересно в глаза коллег посмотреть с таким кодом было бы.

Comment: @And а в чём проблема `do-while`? это стандартный вид цикла. Условие, которое всегда в конце, имхо лучше, чем искать `break` где-то в середине тела цикла

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите `for` (обычный) - то можно просто

```
for(;;) {
    if (c1(a)) {
        a = f1(a);
    }

    if (c2(a)) {
        break;
    }

    a = f2(a);
}
```

Или

```
for(;;a = f2(a)) {
    if (c1(a)) a = f1(a);
    if (c2(a)) break;
}
```

Мне кажется, что так понятнее всего.

Comment: Под обычным я понимаю не содержащий бесконечное условие

Comment: Короче без `break` и `continue`

Comment: @леха у нас goto ещё есть)

Comment: Да и без него тоже

Comment: А у вас нет предварительного условия, которое надо проверять перед выполнением тела цикла.

Comment: @Mikhailo нет, у меня проблема в том что 1 крайняя итерация не умещается в цикл по-другому. И приходится делать лишнию проверку ПОСЛЕ цикла. А если написать с бесконечным и `break` как в вопросе, то всё ок. Но говорят, что это плохой стиль

Comment: Кто говорит - пусть пишут по-другому. Писать нужно так, чтоб было понятно человеку, и чтоб поменьше ошибок делать. Для того и `break` делали, чтобы его применять :)

Answer (score 0):

Если захотите, то можно ещё использовать Go to, но это не советуется использовать. Главное не забывайте, что нужно условие выхода, оно делается через

```
if() {
}
```

Самым практичным является

```
while (true) {
Тело
}
```

Либо

```
for(;;) {
}
```